# How have/how will Indian ground stations be used for comms or tracking of deep space spacecraft?

Tags: deep-space, isro, deep-space-network, doppler-ranging

I have a few data points, but not the big picture.

19-10-2016, the [Giant Metre Wave Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Metrewave_Radio_Telescope) was used to monitor the doppler shift of a beacon signal from the Schiaparelli spacecraft as it descended into the Martian atmosphere. This is a radio telescope for Astronomy research, but was used as an extremely large aperture to collect a signal not necessarily intended for Earth reception. See [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18707/12102) for further discussion.

The [Indian Deep Space Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Deep_Space_Network) in Byalalu supported Chandrayaan-1 in lunar orbit. It then received an upgrade in power and capability, and was used in conjunction with the NASA DSN for the [Mars Orbiter Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Orbiter_Mission). As explained by Dr K Radhakrishnan, the former Director of ISRO [in this video after 51:31](https://youtu.be/tmpzUJbYAEo?t=3091) the deep space capability was developed and proven during MOM's mission. It was also tested or used in some way with [MAVEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAVEN) at Mars as well, but no details are given.

Could someone further explain how the Byalalu ground station has been used with MOM, MAVEN? Does it now have full *deep space* tracking and communications capability? How in the future it might be integrated as a new, networked deep space ground station?

---

**below:** [IDSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Deep_Space_Network)'s 32m dish antenna in Byalalu. Image from [here](http://www.vssc.gov.in/VSSC_V4/index.php/ground-segment/82-chandrayaan-1/967-indian-deep-space-network-idsn).

[image]

**below:** Doppler signal from Schiaparelli, during separation and descent phase, recorded by the [Giant Metre Wave Telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Metrewave_Radio_Telescope). Image from [here](http://blogs.esa.int/rocketscience/2016/10/18/listening-to-an-alien-landing/), more [here](http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~plah/Home_Page_Stuff/GMRT_2006/GMRT_images_2006.html).

[image]

Comment: A bit more about IDSN here: https://youtu.be/Sk0ktxx185I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32 meter antenna of IDSN is being used by JAXA and ISRO to study Venusian atmosphere using signals from Akatsuki probe and Radio occultation technique. ISRO is also planning a Venus mission so these results are of mutual interest.

Excerpt from [Annual Report 2016-17 of Dept. of Space (India)](http://www.isro.gov.in/annual-report-2016-2017-english)

> The space agencies of India and Japan have agreed to further enhance cooperation by signing a new MoU, which enables inclusion of satellite navigation and planetary exploration as additional areas of cooperation. **Both agencies have also agreed to conduct a joint experiment to study Venus atmosphere by collecting signals from JAXA’s Akatsuki mission by ISRO’s ground stations (IDSN).**

A recent paper on results.

"Initial results of the radio occultation experiment in the
Venus orbiter mission Akatsuki"

http://meetingorganizer.copernicus.org/EPSC2017/EPSC2017-403.pdf

> The primary ground station used so far is the 64-m antenna of Usuda Deep Space Center (UDSC) of JAXA. In addition to UDSC, for increasing the number of observation opportunities, we started to use the 32-m antenna of Indian Deep Space Network (IDSN) of Indian Space Research Organization (ISRO) in 2017.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know of the ISRO's involvement in the Venus radioocultation work, or that it was being done at all, so this is very helpful. I see that ISTRAC is mentioned on pages 15-16 of the annual report as well.