# Is there independent evidence that China landed a robot on Mars in May 2021?

Tags: mars, lander, china

I would like to know if there is independent evidence of any kind that China landed a robot on Mars in May 2021?

As of May 16, 2021, the last news on CNSA (China National Space Administration) site is this one:

> Tianwen-1 probe will land on Mars in next few days
>
> Date：2021-05-14
>
> China’s first Mars exploration mission, Tianwen-1 probe has functioned
> normally since its successful launch on July 23rd, 2020. On February
> 10th, 2021, Tianwen-1 probe entered the Martian orbit for scientific
> exploration and huge amount of scientific data are available up to
> date. With the evaluation of the flight status, Tianwen-1 probe is
> scheduled to perform landing campaign targeting Utopia Planitia at the
> proper slot from the early morning of May 15th to May 19th Beijing
> time.

There is no other statement saying that the landing already happened.

By independent evidence I mean things like:

- A UHF carrier, received by another state or hobbyist, that has a frequency drift consistent with a landing on Mars.
- A picture made by MRO showing the Chinese lander on the soil.
- etc.

Xinhua has an article: "China's probe lands on Mars" but the text is vague and quotes CNSA. Nothing is said about the health of the lander/rover and no pictures are available.

> [China's probe lands on Mars](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2021-05/15/c_139947203.htm)
>
> Source: Xinhua| 2021-05-15 10:25:40|Editor: huaxia
>
> [image]
>
> The lander carrying China's first Mars rover has touched down on the
> red planet, the China National Space Administration (CNSA) confirmed
> on Saturday morning.
>
> It is the first time China has landed a probe on a planet other than
> Earth.
>
> The craft's plummet through the Martian atmosphere, lasting about nine
> minutes, was extremely complicated with no ground control, and had to
> be performed by the spacecraft autonomously, said Geng Yan, an
> official at the Lunar Exploration and Space Program Center of the
> CNSA.
>
> Tianwen-1, consisting of an orbiter, a lander and a rover, was
> launched from the Wenchang Spacecraft Launch Site on the coast of
> southern China's island province of Hainan on July 23, 2020.
>
> It was the first step in China's planetary exploration of the solar
> system, with the aim of completing orbiting, landing and roving on the
> red planet in one mission.
>
> The spacecraft entered the Mars orbit in February after a journey of
> nearly seven months through space and spent more than two months
> surveying potential landing sites.
>
> Produced by Xinhua Global Service

Comment: UHF from a low-gain antenna on Mars will be hard to pick up from Earth, but I suppose it is possible. I think there have been previous questions about UHF from Mars to Earth and I answered something about the Green Bank Telescope which can receive such low frequencies. DSN dishes don't go that low as far as I know.  These kinds of verifications generally do happen sooner or later. While Zhurong is not huge the rocket landing will have left a large disturbance in the dust, eventually an orbiter will pass over the right area during the day and try to image that. Stay tuned!

Comment: Here it is [Was the Doppler shift of InSight's “tone” measured and plotted somewhere?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32335) UHF tone monitoring has happened for several mars (and Moon) landing attempts, it's a good question!

Comment: Not an answer since it's just confirmation of the landing attempt https://twitter.com/df2mz/status/1393240504020647941

Comment: **Relevant meta question:** [Should old questions by a deleted user be re-asked so someone can choose the accepted answer?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/26446)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there is.  [This image from HiRISE](https://www.uahirise.org/ESP_069665_2055) shows the landing site of the Zhurong rover on Mars and the rover itself.  See also [BBC page](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-57427797) which has the same image, as well as [this Nature article](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-01588-6)

These images originate from [a NASA orbiter](https://mars.nasa.gov/mro/), which I believe makes them independent.

I think this is moderately convincing evidence.

[image: Zhurong from HiRISE]

---

See [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53662/what-independent-evidence-is-there-that-the-zhurong-rover-landed-on-mars-in-may) which exists so there can be an accepted answer for reference.

Comment: This helps [What's the exact location (lat/lon) of Zhurong?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53586/40257)

Answer (score 8):

> By independent evidence I mean things like:
>
> - A UHF carrier, received by another state or hobbyist, that has a
>   frequency drift consistent with a landing on Mars.

[This page](https://destevez.net/2021/05/tianwen-1-landing/) documents transmissions received around the landing time, received on a 20 m amateur dish.

Videos showing signal analysis are available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/amsatdl/videos).

Update 2021-05-19: CNSA have released two surface pictures and two brief videos showing separation of the lander from the orbiter  [here](http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/english/n6465652/n6465653/c6812028/content.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, Bochum did not track the landing itself: "After the HG antenna signal came back on, Bochum continued tracking the orbiter signal until Mars set at around 23:18 UTC. Bochum cannot track the lander directly. The lander is known to use proximity UHF to communicate with the orbiter, and an X-band beacon developed by Niajing Univ. The UHF link would be extremely weak. For the X-band beacon we didn’t know its frequency, and the signal would be quite weak, so trying to detect it would be like finding a needle in a haystack." (see: https://destevez.net/2021/05/tianwen-1-landing/ )